# How do I change the sidebar title color in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have already managed to change the theme of my vscode, but I am not able to change the color of the area marked below. How do I change?

[image]

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "editor.background": "#001733",
            "sideBar.background":"#001C40",      
            "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#ffffff"
    }
```

Comment: open a different workspace

Comment: Sorry, rioV8. I did not understand. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I put a snippet of my code for you to see.

Comment: in all the themes I have that color is the same as the not-selected-text of the sidebar tree view, maybe try different `sidebar` theme names

Comment: `Explorador` is the sidebar title, I think Garner has found the correct theme name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you’re looking for something like:

```json
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "editor.background": "#001733",
            "sideBar.background":"#001C40",      
            "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#ffffff",
            "sideBarSectionHeader.foreground": "#ffffff"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it includes the line `"sideBarSectionHeader.background": "#001733"` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

"sideBarSectionHeader.background"
and
"sideBarSectionHeader.foreground"